# redirectTo is not defined index.js 20 : angular2 Routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Few days back only I started learning Angular2. I followed documentation step by step and some youtube tutorials as well.

Currently I am facing the issue in configuring the routes. I am using visual studio code for the development.Below are the files content.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './heroComponent/hero-form.component';

import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {ContactusComponent} from './contactUs/contactus.component';
import {AboutusComponent} from './AboutUs/aboutus.component';

export const router:Routes [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path:'contact', component:'ContactusComponent'},
    { path:'about', component:'AboutusComponent'}  
];


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule , FormsModule,RouterModule.forRoot(router)],
  declarations: [ AppComponent , HeroFormComponent, ContactusComponent,AboutusComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

In the above file visual studio code is showing red color on [, : etc, error is `"[ts] is expected"`

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are my some other queries

(1) I saw some Youtube and other tutorials have included `<script src="route.dev.js">` but why angular documentation has not included it. And also in my folder structure inside node_modules there is no folder name angular2, it is @angular.Like this there are many other libraries like RxJx which they have included in there tutorials but angular documentation has not. I am getting confused because of that.**Is it because of different release version of angular2**.

(2) when to include square brackets (array) for routerLink , because in documentation example they have not included it.

Please let me know if you need other files content like tsconfig.json or systemjs.config.js.

Major problem is my application itself is not loading throwing error on console "redirectTo is not defined index.js 20 " .

Did I forgot to include any file??

Any help is appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I should place an `=` at your Routes definition and remove the quotes around the component values:

```
export const router:Routes = [  //<-- here
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path:'contact', component: ContactusComponent},
    { path:'about', component: AboutusComponent}  
];
```

But I would guess you have that. Another problem is that you redirect from `''` to `'/'`. What does that even mean? What are you trying to do there? Better would be to have the path `''` use a component like `HomeComponent` and have a global redirect to `''`:

```
export const router:Routes = [ 
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path:'contact', component: ContactusComponent},
    { path:'about', component: AboutusComponent},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

**additional**

1) Because angular2 was made 'public' in the early alpha status, and because there were a lot of breaking changes from alpha up until the final release, a lot of tutorials and videos you find online are outdated. Best would be to either look at the date it is posted or just to look on the angular.io site. A rule of thumb can be to see if they use `NgModule` in their example. If that's the case, you stumbled across a relatively new tutorial

2) Never (any more). As above, this was the old way to do it. Now everything has been moved to modules, and you only need to import the `RouterModule` in your Module to be able to use all the Router capabilities in your components

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please comment on my some other queries which I raised on the questions